# Why don't some results appear when searching by 'search-term'?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, search

Recently, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-sizet) in SO, then in a comment I got pointed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-sizet-and-int-in-c), which is basically the same.

The issue here is that I searched for the term 'size_t' looking for something relative and the mentioned question didn't appear among the results, or when I typed the question title in 'related questions'.

What is the criteria for searching? IMO, if I search for  I would like to see *all* questions that have (at least) this term in the question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd be better off using Google and searching on stackoverflow.com instead of trying to rely on the search system that is built in.

Comment: New feature request: Replace search box with Google site search.

Comment: @Pesto: This is not a new request at all. Turned down many times, and discussed on the podcast.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing I ever use the StackOverflow search box for is tag searching, and that is it.

Comment: @Rich B: New feature request: Shut up.

Comment: @Pesto: This is not a new request at all. Turned down many times, and discussed on the podcast.

Comment: @Rich B: Oh, I must have missed it because I tried using the site's search system to find it.

Comment: @Pesto: There is your problem. Try searching Uservoice.

Comment: UserVoice: The only site that has a worse search function than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You are also much better off using the external tools. In addition to using:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+size_t

You can use things like:

> http://askjonskeet.com/

Comment: Apparently Jon Skeet doesn't know much about `size_t`, sadly.  Or at least, he hasn't felt the need to share that knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come to accept that the search system is far less reliable than the memory of other users.  It's kind of like a distributed search through pedantry.

Also, creating a question with the title "What is size_t in C++?" causes the system to not even be able to provide a similar question, even though they obviously exist.  Actually, this is *really* messed up.  The question title "What is size`_`t in C++?" doesn't work, but "What is size`_`t in sdfsdklfjdsf?" gives possible duplicates.  Who wrote this thing?!