# Example of really bad search in SO

Tags: discussion, search

Search for "what is a monad" in SO.  The first page of search results does not include the question [what is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) which has been favorited and upvoted over ten times.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+a+monad

Comment: @Marc thanks for adding the "discussion" tag

Comment: (we're trying to categorise everything as "bug", "feature-request", "discussion", etc; if you think it is one of the other two, just re-tag it)

Comment: Maybe you can be interested in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/why-dont-some-results-appear-when-searching-by-search-term

Comment: see my response, below -- try it again

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but google finds it [virtually at the top](http://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+monad), so all is not lost ;-p

I do wonder if the site can't just use google for the search; ideally site-specific ([custom search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/)), but heck, vanilla would do.

Comment: Yes, power it with Google/Bing.

Answer (score 4):

A few recent changes in search..

1. Search now *HEAVILY* weights title in the results, since people seemed to really like that approach (used on the /ask page, which searched exclusively on title alone).
2. Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches. So if you enter

   > c++ entities

   it will convert to

   > [c++] entities

   automagically.

Try again and see if it is more to your liking.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+a+monad

Comment: This has frustrated me as well, when i *know* i remember a portion of a title, but can't find the question among all the others that include that phrase in their bodies. But something still seems screwy: why doesn't this search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22where%20can%20i%20ask%20questions%22

... immediately produce this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions   

?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the stopword list, but have you tried specifying you want highest voted results first? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22where%20can%20i%20ask%20questions%22&tab=votes

Comment: also try searching for "programming questions" with the quotes. Avoiding stopwords seems to be the magic ingredient here.

Comment: Damn stopwords...

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty common knowledge right now that Google searching StackOverflow (and related sites) is much better than using the StackOverflow search.

You could also try http://www.askjonskeet.com, but I would still stick with Google.